# Playing video in Android app with native player

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm new with building apps
I made it with eclipse to compile and phonegab.

A while ago I made a android app with video content.
It did work in the past, but not anymore.

I did it with a direct link
such as Play

When you click the link, Android used the "native"player. Thats what I want, but that doesn't work anymore.

Can anybody give me some advise or tell me why it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: abra-ka-dabra...